# PHP Fractals (transformers) outputs some strange json

Tags: php, json

So I don't know if this is the norm, but this json doesn't look easy to use, especially for front end developers.

So using [these docs](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/) I did a default include for posts on a blog, the transformers are:

```
<?php

namespace App\Etis\Domain\Transformers\Blog;

use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;
use App\Etis\Domain\Entities\BlogsEntity;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Etis\Domain\Transformers\Blog\Posts\PostsTransformer;

class BlogsTransformer extends TransformerAbstract {

    protected $defaultIncludes = [
        'posts'
    ];

    public function transform(BlogsEntity $blog) {

        return [
            'id'                => $blog->id,
            'belongs_to_user'   => $blog->user_id,
            'title'             => $blog->title,
            'created_at'        => $blog->created_at->format(Carbon::ISO8601),
            'updated_at'        => $blog->updated_at->format(Carbon::ISO8601)
        ];
    }

    public function includePosts(BlogsEntity $blog) {
        $posts = $blog->posts;

        return $this->collection($posts, new PostsTransformer);
    }
}
```

The above is the blog transformer, which as we can see includes posts, so lets see that transformer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Etis\Domain\Transformers\Blog\Posts;

use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;
use App\Etis\Domain\Entities\PostsEntity;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class PostsTransformer extends TransformerAbstract {

    public function transform(PostsEntity $post) {
        return [
            'id'          => $post->id,
            'title'       => $post->title,
            'content'     => $post->content,
            'blog_id'     => $post->blog_id,
            'published'   => $post->published,
            'slug'        => $post->slug,
            'saved'       => $post->saved,
            'created_at'  => $post->created_at->format(Carbon::ISO8601),
            'updated_at'  => $post->updated_at->format(Carbon::ISO8601)
        ];
    }
}
```

Super simple, nothing complicated.

```
{  
   data:[  
      {  
         type:"blogs",
         id:"2",
         attributes:{  
            belongs_to_user:2,
            title:"Everymans Thoughts",
            created_at:"2016-04-28T16:14:48+0000",
            updated_at:"2016-04-28T16:14:48+0000"
         },
         relationships:{  
            posts:{  
               data:[  
                  {  
                     type:null,
                     id:"2"
                  },
                  {  
                     type:null,
                     id:"3"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         type:"blogs",
         id:"1",
         attributes:{  
            belongs_to_user:1,
            title:"GNI2BOWLHy",
            created_at:"2016-04-22T19:56:23+0000",
            updated_at:"2016-04-22T19:56:23+0000"
         },
         relationships:{  
            posts:{  
               data:[  
                  {  
                     type:null,
                     id:"1"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   included:[  
      {  
         type:null,
         id:"2",
         attributes:{  
            title:"Sample Blog",
            content:"<p><img src="            http://lorempixel.com/900/400/" alt="Image" /></p> <p>Lorem markdownum Hymenaee. <em>Triste</em> tamen? Sed herbas opibusque ratem placebant timor Trachinia libera verba opem teste aquaticus ne est paulum ipse Aesonides?</p> <p>Lorem markdownum Hymenaee. <em>Triste</em> tamen? Sed herbas opibusque ratem placebant timor Trachinia libera verba opem teste aquaticus ne est paulum ipse Aesonides?</p> <p>Lorem markdownum Hymenaee. <em>Triste</em> tamen? Sed herbas opibusque ratem placebant timor Trachinia libera verba opem teste aquaticus ne est paulum ipse Aesonides? if (operation_bitrate_cron.gpsOsEmulation(kde_terahertz_qwerty,
            gigabyte( mask) + surfaceKeywords))            {  
               partition_whois += 2 + -2;
            }            memory *= portalLink; hdmi_tween = user.signature(mcaBooleanBatch * 54,
            header(driveDatabase),
            ip_latency);</p> <h2>Prope eripe consorte natis virgo appellant venisset</h2> <p>Gente cum audito nymphae <a href="http://hipstermerkel.tumblr.com/">levati veri ictibus</a>,
            aut arida,
            quantumque. Modo insistit <strong>quidem</strong>:satis parvos edaci totiens spectare,
            alto huic suis facitis nondum. Sorores <a href="http://www.thesecretofinvisibility.com/">oblita</a>,
            in ait pascas,
            tantum iam; speciem,
            labefactum. Postquam <strong>ager</strong> Talibus turba non uberrima,
            pulchro et quibus sententia munitos dum,
            et aquarum dubiae,
            pars. Terga vellet de Emathion Phlegyis Circes peremptam siccat,
            me suis Prochytenque.</p> <h2>A nostra</h2> <p>Paternos nequeunt,
            rapta,
            velles; fugisse his tergo plurima! Veni cognita cavernis et tergo interrumpente terra; nec ortus videtur cumque nunc! Dubitanti frater nunc moras tuque,
            est litore Plura. Haec color Ceres nitidis oculus,
            cum squamae,
            crede australem in abiere,
            te plebemque lentum!</p> <h2>Ab haec condi et suum memorabile nequiquam</h2> <p>Vulneribus docuique ridentem monstravit et <a href="http://gifctrl.com/">intacta vomit terroris</a> pia ille festumque iterque nunc,
            quamvis. Subito quid. Ad pariente mihi facto hortatibus nisi tamen pulsat dolor ac se,
            ille in orant quodcumque guttur,
            rite.</p> <blockquote> <p>Vultus Aiaci his picto,
            comitique huic,
            ferro:est certi,
            sententia commissas mater. Superi tabuerint terras intravit inertes conorque aurum reus mentas caelo ut et sintque:            <em>feruntur usus</em>. <a href="http://zombo.com/">Illa avsis noxque</a>,
            sua Bacchumque comminus positus. Cur igne paulatim?</p> </blockquote> <p>Non gauderet,
            vellere,
            auro halitus,
            fortuna non Picus me alios Cerberei potentes. Aquis praelatus soceri densa!</p> ",
            blog_id:2,
            published:true,
            slug:"sample-blog",
            saved:false,
            created_at:"2016-04-28T16:16:52+0000",
            updated_at:"2016-04-30T18:25:49+0000"
         }
      },
      {  
         type:null,
         id:"3",
         attributes:{  
            title:"asdasdasda",
            content:"<p>asdasdsadsa</p> ",
            blog_id:2,
            published:false,
            slug:"asdasdasda",
            saved:true,
            created_at:"2016-05-14T16:53:12+0000",
            updated_at:"2016-05-14T16:53:12+0000"
         }
      },
      {  
         type:null,
         id:"1",
         attributes:{  
            title:"yTxxDi0EwD",
            content:"YQzrVXMB5bXepspPNp0RLaCoqXYrWPgEvcZxcISrGcFBPFxic8KsdRYpvMLPlZenoJIlI2fpSwxbeTMtWDHZW8Z5fnUBBn6lTiVz",
            blog_id:1,
            published:true,
            slug:"ytxxdi0ewd",
            saved:false,
            created_at:"2016-04-22T19:56:23+0000",
            updated_at:"2016-04-22T19:56:23+0000"
         }
      }
   ],
   meta:{  
      pagination:{  
         total:2,
         count:2,
         per_page:15,
         current_page:1,
         total_pages:1,
         links:[  

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

How do I use these transformers to get said JSON?

I have a controller method:

```
public function getBlogs() {
    $manager = new Manager();
    $manager->setSerializer(new JsonApiSerializer());

    if (\Auth::check()) {
      $paginatedBlogs = BlogsEntity::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate();
      $blogs          = $paginatedBlogs->getCollection();

      $resource = new Collection($blogs, new BlogsTransformer(), 'blogs');
      $resource->setPaginator(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($paginatedBlogs));

      return $manager->createData($resource)->toArray();
    } else {
      return response()->json(['error_message' => 'You cannot access this route.']);
    }
}
```

1. **So why am I getting the really ugly JSON thats like impossible to use?**
2. **Why are the posts not nested under their respective
   blogs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$manager->setSerializer(new JsonApiSerializer());` sets Fractal to output JSON-API compliant JSON, which has a very particular spec (http://jsonapi.org/). If you don't want its complicated (but standardized, which is potentially very useful to front-end folks) output, [use a different (like the default one) serializer](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/serializers/).

Comment: While I agree, if you looked at my json out put the posts that belong to the blog should have been nested under the blog (or with in it) so I switched to array serializer, which properly nests things. Thanks

Comment: @TheWebs I did look at your JSON. That's how the JSON-API spec says it should happen - the posts that belong to the blog are referenced by ID, and their data is in the `included`. Logic to connect them is up to the front-end folks. You wrote or copied the bit that turns on JSON-API - don't blame me for not knowing what it entails. :-)

Comment: I dont blame you. I just prefer to serve up simpler JSON thats nested to show relationships instead of making the front end developer have to add additional logic to go searching for related elements and nodes. LOL